# How should I accomplish this complex string replace with vba?

Tags: vba, excel

I need to accomplish the following:

[image: before]

becomes

[image: after]

Basically insert spaces between number headers (1.0, 1.1, 1.2, insert Space if one doesn't already exist...)

And also if a number doesn't exist, add it in. (as in the 'before' picture 2.0 and 6.0 are missing)

I figured out how to create an array to check the data as follows:

```
Dim myRange As Range, c As Range
Dim x As Integer, i As Integer, arSize As Integer, y As Integer
Dim myArray() As String
x = 1
arSize = Int(Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
ReDim myArray(1 To arSize)
Set myRange = Range("B1", Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
For Each c In myRange
    If IsEmpty(c) = True Then
    myArray(x) = 0
    Else
        If IsNumeric(Left(c, 1)) = True Then
            myArray(x) = Val(Left(c, 1))
        Else: myArray(x) = -1
        End If
    End If
x = x + 1
Next
'for debugging:
For i = 1 To UBound(myArray)
    Range("F" & i).Value = myArray(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

(if first character is a number, then add the number to the array element; if it is not a number then set the element to -1, if it is blank then set the element to 0)

Just need some advice please or an example of how I can manipulate the data to achive my goal.  Thank you very much.  Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ideas seem to be more or less clear on the data-management/-iterating fronts although the approach you have chosen for this specific problem does not seem the ideal one to me. I would rather rely on Excel cells than on an array (able to store more information, easy to be copied and with a structure equivalent to the destination format you can relate to). As far as it is not too easy to explain all the required changes, I have preferred to write down an algorithm performing the actions you want (ironically, after having critised this proceeding a short while ago :)). Bear in mind that this code relies on a "temporary column" (C by default) to store all the changes, which is cleared after the whole process has been completed. Please, feel free to inquire about any bit which is not clear (I am posting this for you to understand everything, not just to execute it).

```
Dim col2 As String: col2 = "C"
Dim firstRow As Integer: firstRow = 2
Set myRange = Range("B" & firstRow, Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
Dim prevIndex As Integer: prevIndex = 1
Dim curRow As Long: curRow = firstRow - 1
For Each c In myRange
    curRow = curRow + 1
    Dim consecutive As Integer: consecutive = 0
    If Not IsEmpty(c) Then
        Dim written As Boolean: written = False
        Dim numRightBefore As Boolean: numRightBefore = False
        If IsNumeric(Left(c, 1)) = True Then
            Dim curIndex As Integer: curIndex = CInt(Left(c, 1))
            If (curIndex <> prevIndex) Then
               If (curIndex < prevIndex) Then
                   'Something went wrong
                   Exit For
               Else
                  If (curIndex = prevIndex + 1) Then
                      'Normal situation -> consecutive index
                      prevIndex = curIndex
                      If (consecutive <> 0) Then
                          Range(col2 & curRow).Value = ""
                          curRow = curRow + 1
                      End If
                  Else
                     Do While (curIndex > prevIndex + 1)
                        If (consecutive = 0) Then
                            Range(col2 & curRow).Value = ""
                            consecutive = 1
                         Else
                            curRow = curRow + 1
                         End If
                         prevIndex = prevIndex + 1
                         Range(col2 & curRow).Value = CStr(prevIndex) & ".0 text"
                         curRow = curRow + 1
                     Loop
                      prevIndex = prevIndex + 1
                      Range(col2 & curRow).Value = ""
                      curRow = curRow + 1
                  End If
               End If
            End If
        End If

        If (Not written) Then
            Range(col2 & curRow).Value = c.Value
        End If
        consecutive = curIndex
    End If
Next


Range(col2 & firstRow & ":" & col2 & curRow).Copy
myRange.PasteSpecial
Range(col2 & firstRow & ":" & col2 & curRow).Clear
```

NOTE: **it is not recommendable to create too big arrays**. The exact limits depend upon the power of the computer (its memory) and the current conditions (further programs being run). Also it should be noted that I did experience some problems in the past with VBA and big arrays thus I prefer to be even more cautious here. In general (in any programming language), I rarely declare a 1D array with a size higher than 5000.

NOTE2: **reading/writing to Excel cells** is, from a performance point of view, a pretty bad approach. **I am not recommending to rely on this in general** (not even by default). I thought that it was a good idea under these specific conditions: unclear size of the input data and depicting an approach the OP might be able to relate easily to. I personally would rely on arrays and, over certain size, on temporary files (much faster than reading/writing from Excel).

Comment: This works. I can understand how to modify it to my needs (and already have) I have run into an issue where the last heading is missing so I will have to play with this to figure out how to check and add it.  for example:  there are supposed to be exactly 9 headers.  Your code works fine unless I happen to be missing heading 9.

Comment: @MatthewPaulin this code is expecting you to change the input conditions. You can write the row you want to start from or the column or anything. What you mean with missing heading 9?

Comment: +1, returning the favor, and you used an approach more suited for those still learning :)

Comment: @varocarbas I need to add a check at the end for any headings that might be missing after the existing data.  i.e. if only 1-8 exist then it won't check for missing 9... or if only 1-6 exist then it won't insert 7-9. I also need to auto-insert a space at the end of heading section 9 (these are on my todo list).  Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @MatthewPaulin No problem. So, I understand that you can deal with these issues by your own. Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim arrLines() As String
    Dim varLine As Variant
    Dim varLineStart As Variant
    Dim LineIndex As Long
    Dim lCounter As Long
    Dim lInterval As Long

    lCounter = 1
    lInterval = 5000
    ReDim arrLines(1 To lInterval)

    For Each varLine In Range("B2", Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)).Value
        LineIndex = LineIndex + 1
        varLineStart = Trim(Left(Replace(Trim(varLine), " ", String(99, " ")), 99))
        If IsNumeric(varLineStart) Then
            varLineStart = Int(varLineStart)
            If varLineStart > lCounter Then
                lCounter = lCounter + 1
                Do While varLineStart > lCounter
                    If Len(arrLines(LineIndex - 1)) = 0 Then
                        If LineIndex > UBound(arrLines) Then ReDim Preserve arrLines(1 To UBound(arrLines) + lInterval)
                        arrLines(LineIndex) = lCounter & ".0 text"
                        lCounter = lCounter + 1
                        LineIndex = LineIndex + 1
                    End If
                    LineIndex = LineIndex + 1
                Loop
                If Len(arrLines(LineIndex - 1)) > 0 Then LineIndex = LineIndex + 1
            End If
        End If
        If LineIndex > UBound(arrLines) Then ReDim Preserve arrLines(1 To UBound(arrLines) + lInterval)
        arrLines(LineIndex) = varLine
    Next varLine

    If LineIndex > 1 Then
        ReDim Preserve arrLines(1 To LineIndex)
        Range("C2").Resize(LineIndex).Value = Application.Transpose(arrLines)
    End If

    Erase arrLines

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you suggesting to rely on an array with a size of 65000?! Nothing to say about your algorithm (mine does some things differently, but nothing to complain about).

Comment: In most cases that will be more than enough lines.  I figure if it doesn't work the asker would let me know and it can be adjusted.

Comment: I didn't mean that (65000 is surely more than enough); I meant that relying on so big arrays is not a good practice. Your approach is fine and don't think that the OP will be dealing with more than 1000 lines.

Comment: I find it better practice than using redim preserve which is an expensive and awkward call.  And when there is an unknown number of elements that will be needed, going higher than expected is fine.  Creating a one-dimensional string-type array of 65000 elements will reserve about 635 kb of memory while the code runs.  Most modern machines have at minimum 1 gb of memory so 635 kb is generally trivial.  That being said, it is still faster and more efficient than writing to the worksheet one cell at a time, which is always bad practice.

Comment: Somehow this fails at properly checking if a space already exists.  It adds extra blank cells.  I would figure out how to fix if I could wrap my feeble brain around this: `varLineStart = Trim(Left(Replace(Trim(varLine), " ", String(99, " ")), 99))`

Comment: Logically writing/reading from the worksheet is horrible from a performance point of view; there is no discussion there. But in this case, with an undefinedly big input set and an OP who does not have the ideas completely clear, I thought that would be the best approach. What you are saying about memory is pretty inaccurate: the memory is shared by all the programs running on the computer, what you cannot determine a priori. Even the macro itself might have more arrays than just this one. Recommending to set up a so big array is a quite bad advice. I will update my answer now.

Comment: @MatthewPaulin my approach faces this different and thus not care about the contents, other than the heading number.

Comment: I have written a clarification regarding how inadequate is reading/writing to cells from a performance point of view. Are you planning to continue sticking to your "dimensioning an array with a size of 65000 is acceptable"?

Comment: varocarbas, I still say that it is very unlikely that using a dimensioned array of 65000 will cause any issues.  Anybody could easily change the upper limit to be a smaller number to better fit their requirements, like `1 to 5000`.  If preferred, it could be made into a dynamic array and then use `ReDim Preserve arr(1 to LineIndex)` at the index.  Personally, using a size 65000 array has never presented an issue for myself or anybody I've provided a solution for, but if you feel so strongly about it I can adjust this answer.

Comment: @MatthewPaulin regarding existing blank cells, I have edited my answer to accomodate.

Comment: @varocarbas I have edited my answer to use a dynamic array that increases its upper bound at intervals of 5000 instead of a fixed size array of 65000.  Is that something more along the lines you would prefer to see?

Comment: I do think that a so big size in a relatively complex program (with quite a few arrays) might represent a problem and I do have experienced in the past issues in VBA with big arrays (and smaller than 65000). On top of all this, I do think that there are quite a few people (potential readers of VBA posts) with less powerful computers than yours for whom this might become an issue even in the simplest situation. I don't think that reading/writing to Excel for a so simple problem would be really bad but I have warned it just in case.

Comment: Thank you both.  I have added both of your codes to my wb so that I can play with them.  Honestly most of the code I have I set up to loop through hundreds to thousands of worksheets including complex database queries and I have yet to see any noticible slowdown regardless of the method used.  I was actually at first trying(unseccessfully) to create a second dynamic array to hold the modified data from the first dynamic array but I couldn't get the redims to work properly.

Comment: @Tigeravatar I really appreciate you taking the time to help.  I chose varocarbas answer as correct only because it was the first one that worked out of the box and was able to easily modify to suit my needs.  That is not to say yours was any less correct and again I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the version of my macro for reference.  I am referencing named constants in the case select.

```
Sub varocarbas()
Dim col2 As String: col2 = "C"
Dim firstRow As Integer: firstRow = 2
Set myRange = Range("B" & firstRow, Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
Dim prevIndex As Integer: prevIndex = 1
Dim curRow As Long: curRow = firstRow - 1
For Each c In myRange
    curRow = curRow + 1


  Dim consecutive As Integer: consecutive = 0
    If Not IsEmpty(c) Then
        Dim written As Boolean: written = False
        Dim numRightBefore As Boolean: numRightBefore = False
        If IsNumeric(Left(c, 1)) = True Then
            Dim curIndex As Integer: curIndex = CInt(Left(c, 1))
            If (curIndex <> prevIndex) Then
               If (curIndex < prevIndex) Then
                   'Something went wrong
                   Exit For
               Else
                  If (curIndex = prevIndex + 1) Then
                      'Normal situation -> consecutive index
                      prevIndex = curIndex
                      If (consecutive <> 0) Then
                          Range(col2 & curRow).Value = ""
                          curRow = curRow + 1
                      End If
                  Else
                     Do While (curIndex > prevIndex + 1)
                        If (consecutive = 0) Then
                            Range(col2 & curRow).Value = ""
                            consecutive = 1
                         Else
                            curRow = curRow + 1
                         End If
                         prevIndex = prevIndex + 1
                            Dim sHeading As String
                         Select Case prevIndex
                            Case 1
                                sHeading = cIN
                            Case 2
                                sHeading = cTL
                            Case 3
                                sHeading = cPP
                            Case 4
                                sHeading = cRF
                            Case 5
                                sHeading = cPL
                            Case 6
                                sHeading = cPM
                            Case 7
                                sHeading = cPR
                            Case 8
                                sHeading = cRS
                            Case 9
                                sHeading = cCP
                            End Select
                         Range(col2 & curRow).Value = CStr(prevIndex) & ".0 " & sHeading
                         curRow = curRow + 1
                     Loop
                      prevIndex = prevIndex + 1
                      Range(col2 & curRow).Value = ""
                      curRow = curRow + 1
                  End If
               End If
            End If
        End If

        If (Not written) Then
            Range(col2 & curRow).Value = c.Value
        End If
        consecutive = curIndex
    End If
Next


Range(col2 & firstRow & ":" & col2 & curRow).Copy
myRange.PasteSpecial
Range(col2 & firstRow & ":" & col2 & curRow).Clear
End Sub
```